# How to get Status of All VM's in VM Scale set in a Watchdog

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, watchdog, azure-vm-scale-set, azure-vm

I am working to create a watchdog to see if the VM's in VMScaleSet is accessible from my SF Cluster.
To do this I am creating a watchdog and looking for a Rest Endpoint or any Method I can invoke to check the status of VM's in a Scale Set.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get Azure VM scale set instances' status, you can get the following the rest API. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinescalesetvms/list)

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}
/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}
/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets
/{virtualMachineScaleSetName}/virtualMachines?api-version=2020-06-01&$expand=instanceView
```

For example

1. Create a service principal and assign Azure RABC `Contributor` role to the sp
2. Get the token

```
POST /hanxia.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type =client_credentials
&client_id=<sp app id>
&client_secret=<sp client secret>
&resource=https://management.azure.com/
```

3. Call the API

```
GET /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachineScaleSets/{virtualMachineScaleSetName}/virtualMachines?api-version=2020-06-01&$expand=instanceView HTTP/1.1
Host: management.azure.com
Authorization:  Bearer <access_token>
```

After running the API, it will return the instance's status in the response body property `status`
[image]